# How to load react app at say localhost:3000/home instead of localhost:3000?

Tags: reactjs

As mentioned above, how to load my app at localhost:3000/home at the start and not localhost:3000. I usually just run npm start in console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `react-router-dom`.

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-w1in3e?file=index.js

See following example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import About from './components/About';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Topics from './components/Topics';

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={() => (<Redirect to='/home' />)} />
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

render(<BasicExample />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `package.json` to

```
"start": "npm run build",
"build": "webpack -d && cp src/home.html dist/home.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback",
"build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/home.html dist/home.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Router, You can also indicate basename into the react router.

```
 <Router basename="home">
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Router>
```

more info about basename: 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

suggestion of @Akshay Milmile is good

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for you, but if you add `"homepage":"/home"` into package.json your project should start from `localhost:3000/home`.

```json
{
  "name": "HMS",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/home",
  "dependencies": {
```